How to find and store which row of a Pandas DataFrame matches another DataFrame row?
Warning: I am new to python and Pandas.
I have two dataframes, storing information about statistical tests I am carrying out. One that has a potentially large number of rows, called prevtests, and one which has a smaller number of rows called tests. They both have columns called 'p', 'n' and 'a', as well as other columns that don't match.
I consider a row from tests to match a row from prevtests if they have the same values of 'p', 'n' and 'a'. I want to fill a column in tests called 'index' with the index of the row in prevtests that matches it, if there is a match. I want to use this to be able to quickly update prevtests based on values in tests, without searching for matches each time. I don't think combining the two into one dataframe is a good solution, as I want to iterate over the rows of the smaller one (tests).

I have found many answers about returning matching rows, or entries in a list, but these all work by converting to a set, which deletes the index information.
The best solution I can come up with is to do an inner merge of both dataframes (dropping the irrelevant columns), to get a dataframe small enough to be quickly iterated over, then iterate over tests and the new dataframe in base python looking for matching rows, and individually assign each value in 'index'. This is O(n^2) in the size of tests, but should still be computationally manageable. I also don't think I can make tests a view of prevtests, because it contains columns that prevtests doesn't.
But this seems hideously convoluted and needlessly slow. Is there a nice way of doing this that isn't slow? (I consider O(size of tests * size of prevtests) to be slow).

refer to this when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You can join dataframes on columns you want to match:
tests = tests.merge(
    prevtests[['p', 'n', 'a', 'index']],
    how='left',
    on=['p', 'n', 'a']
)

This approach works if there are no duplicates in the prevtests (by p, n, a columns). You can use prevtests.drop_duplicates(subset=['p', 'n', 'a']) if there are some.
Also, I assume there is no column with the name 'index' in tests. You can use the suffixes parameter of the merge method.
Here is the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
